# Ubuntu freezes after using keyboard or mouse

Tags: 14.04

[image]

Today I switched from Windows to Ubuntu 14.04.1(64-bit), I've used Ubuntu before on another computer and it works completely fine with no issues. On this computer, everything installed fine, and I got the message to reboot and the CD ejected. Then once the computer computer comes back on I get about 4 seconds of the purple colored Ubuntu screen and then it proceeds to the Desktop (I opted-in to lock in automatically) and after moving the mouse in about 3 seconds the computer freezes and that goes on for about 10 more seconds. And then it turns into the mess in the picture.

My computer model is eMachines el1333g 2GB RAM, got it about 3 or 4 years back.

I saw someone else with this problem that had an emachines computer and their solution was to make sure the .iso was valid and not corrupted, so I re-downloaded and erased & installed and got the same thing.

EDIT: also tried Mint, does the same thing after automatic boot up showing the desktop with the Install icon. And forgot to mention it's not the keyboard and mouse, I tried it with them in and it still froze.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I feel confident you will continue to use Ubuntu in the future, even if  you can never make it work on that one computer, I am offering you this one valuable piece of advice;  "Prior to installing ubuntu on ANY pc, always put it through its paces using a live CD or flashdrive".  I tell that to everyone.  It is never safe to assume Ubuntu will work correctly on one computer because you've used it successfully on another.

Many times people wipe out dying Windows installations expecting Ubuntu to be the panacea, only to discover that the real reason windows appeared to be dying is that the hard drive or other hardware components were failing.  In so much as you are using an eMachines, it seems extremely likely.

Now, if you'll allow me, I'll offer you the REAL solution, and one which even eMachines haters will approve of.  It is the solution I was forced to use with the last two eMachines brought to me.  REPLACE THE MOTHERBOARD.  If yours is one which will accept a standard mini-ATX such as a Gigabyte 78LMT, or a similar ASUS such as the M5A78L-M, you might be much happier with the result than buying an entirely new pc.

I kid you not when I tell you I have yet to encounter an emachines which lasted more than about one year and didn't die emitting burnt insulation odors from chips on its motherboard.  They seem designed to fail, but replace the motherboard and you can experience gaming performance at a budget price.

Comment: could you point me in the direction towards the motherboard you think is best?

Comment: Ironically, I listed in my answer the two motherboards I have purchased for such used PC upgrade/builds in the past 12 months.  I was so pleased that I purchased one of each for my girlfriend and myself.  I'm at my girlfriend's at the moment using the Gigabyte brand motherboard I purchased for her build.

I am pleased with both of them.  I'm slightly more pleased with the ASUS in some ways, and with the Gigabyte in still others.  Please note that neither of those two motherboards will accept your old CPU, though there is a slight but low possibility they will accept your existing RAM.

Answer (score 0):

With other Linux versions running into the same issue, I would think it is an incompatibility with your hardware and Linux, specifically something wrong with your video hardware. The Nvidia hardware on that computer actually does have supported Linux drivers, so I really don't believe it is a software issue.

Just for troubleshooting's sake, have you tried the 32-bit version? Since you only have 2gb of RAM, switching down to the 32-bit shouldn't make *that* much of a performance difference, but **could** provide a different result regarding any hardware conflicts you have with the 64-bit version.

Comment: Nevermind it did not work with Mint, trying Ubuntu atm..

Comment: @LeeGriffin Actually, your CPU should be an Athlon 2580e, which IS a 64-bit CPU. But, being an eMachines computer (A super-cheap Acer computer), it is hard telling how their mainboard's firmware is set up or what settings are on you BIOS regarding your CPU. You BIOS CPU settings may be something to take a look at... If it didn't work with 32-bit Mint, I doubt it will Ubuntu either. Your hardware may simply not be fully compatible/supported with Linux.

Comment: yeah it didnt work with that either... What can i do since i erased windows, or do you know of anything els ethat will work?

Comment: @LeeGriffin I would recommend following gyropyge's advice; I have had similar experiences with eMachines and have replaced the MB on many of them for customers. You should be able to replace the MB with one of gyropyges's suggestions and have a much better experience overall with that machine. You should be able to purchase one of those MB's for around $50-$60 USD, which is far less expensive than buying a whole new computer.